# Loop Through Tickers

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I have a program that opens a stock's data file, feeds it to a function which turns the date into a datetime index, and then returns the file and outputs it as a csv. It works fine, here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd

def clean_func(f1):
    f1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(f1['Date']) 
    f1.index = f1['Date']
    return f1
    
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\\path\\tkr.csv')
df1 = clean_func(df)
df1.to_csv('C:\\path\\tkr.csv')
```

Rather than have redundant lines of code for each ticker ("tkr" above), I'd like to create a list of ticker symbols and loop through them. I'm not sure how embed everything correctly to loop through a list hence this post. Please advise.

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried, and what went wrong with your attempts? For example: `ticker_list=['a','b','c']; for i in ticker_list:???`

Comment: I didn't try anything due to a lack of familiarity. The larger architecture/structure of code can be a little confusing. What is local/global, where do indents work vs not, etc.. Clearly, per the approved answer below, the answer was easy but you have to have the knowledge. Any thoughts on where to become more versed on code architecture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put them in a for loop with format strings (f-strings) like this:

```
import pandas as pd

def clean_func(f1):
    f1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(f1['Date']) 
    f1.index = f1['Date']
    return f1
    
tkrs = ['tkr1', 'tkr2', 'tkr3']
for tkr in tkrs:
    df = pd.read_csv(f'C:\\path\\{tkr}.csv')
    df1 = clean_func(df)
    df1.to_csv(f'C:\\path\\{tkr}.csv')
```

Comment: One question, what is the significance/meaning of the 'f' in your paths above? I don't know the right vocabulary to search myself. Thanks

Comment: That syntax is called a f-string or format string, and it allows you to insert python expressions between the curly braces `{}` inside a string.  Real Python has a good write up on this syntax here: https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/#f-strings-a-new-and-improved-way-to-format-strings-in-python